# imageview image fill fit modes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view cell, [prototype], in which I added a imageview. Now I set the height and width of this imageview manually in the size inspector. However I'm using

```
[cell viewWithTag:12345]
```

to get the view pointer in my objective c code, and updating the image of the image view. However I find that my manual constraints are overridden, and the image takes its own size. I have tried various modes (Aspect fill, Aspect Fit, etc.) both in the attributes inspectors and programmatically.

So my question is how can I set the constraints? Where am I wrong? Why are they not working?

Comment: You have asked a question about constraints of UIImageView and checked an answer about resizing UIImage? Maybe you should ask your questions clearer...

Comment: sorry about that. It solved me for now, so I just clicked it as answer. If I find any other answer which solves, again I will make that answer too. My only intention was, if someone lands up on this page, they will know which all worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would check if the problem lies on contentMode of image view or size of image view. It is also possible that your imageview is resized because of autoresizing mask. If you initialize your image view with

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
```

method your imageview will be automatically resized to the size of image.

Comment: My initialisation is as follows : UIImageView *imageThumbnail = (UIImageView*) [cell viewWithTag:12345];

Comment: it is not init method. You are only getting UIImageView instance, which you already have. How do you create them? And how do you set image?

Comment: imageThumbnail.image (imageThumbnail is the imageView*) = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbSmallURL]]

Comment: Ohh I see you point. So how should to proceed to stop the overriding

Comment: The way you do does not change the size of imageview. I assume you set the frame your self and you do not want to change size? You can set a breakpoint (eg. in didSelectRowAtIndexPath) and check the frame of your imageview and content mode. Do you use the tableview in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Following code is helpfull

**Case 1:**

```
   -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100.0;
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        image.tag = 101;
        [cell addSubview:image];
    }
    UIImageView *imageObj =(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    [imageObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"url.jpeg"]];

    // Set up the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

OUT put: 
[image]

**And Case2:**

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 200.0;
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        image.tag = 101;
        [cell addSubview:image];
    }
    UIImageView *imageObj =(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    [imageObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"url.jpeg"]];

    // Set up the cell...


    return cell;
}
```

Out put:
[image]

Actual image size is 460 x 246 but you can find difference according to frame

Thank you